# Visual Studio Remote Compile and Run

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, ide

I am trying to figure out if it is possible to use Visual Studio 2012 as a full linux development suite. I know this is not the regular question here but work with me. What i have so far is the ability to use Visual Studio as a text editor to edit inside a virtual machine of Linux running on my computer.

The way that I have done this is to set up a permanent ssh portal that acts as as a hard drive in my windows. I have done this using a program called WebDrive:

[image]

So that is cool, it means I have the ability to fully view my Linux c++ project from Visual Studio. This provides all of the cool c++ editing things that i like about visual studio.

*So where to from here?*

Basically what I have now is a heavy glorified text editor.

What I would like to do is get the whole 'shabam' working.

**I would like to be able to compile and run code from visual studio remotely on a server address.** Is it possible? The code is built with cmake and g++ compiler?

Comment: I'm not sure if Visual Studio's compiler will work with Linux. I think you could write a plugin for Visual Studio that communicates with something on Linux, to run the built product, and have Visual Studio build to the shared folder -> tell linux to run.,

Comment: Ok, that seems complex, would i be able to use the debugger in VS this way do you think?

Comment: Visual studio only has the ability to attach to processes running on the local machine. I dobut it has the ability to attach to processes running within processes (virtual machines).

Comment: @ChristianStewart actually Visual Studio is able to do remote debugging too, but I'm not sure how that would work if the remote machine is not Windows.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bt727f1t.aspx

Comment: @NateHekman It looks like that debugging is only for external windows machines.

Comment: FYI WebDrive costs money but win-SSHFS is free. https://code.google.com/p/win-sshfs/downloads/list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your best bet would be http://www.wingdb.com/. WinGDB allows working within VS studio and compiling on a remote Linux machine directly. Full step through debugging within VS is supported. For DLLs you can attach to remote process running on your Linux build server within VS. Great solution for working within the kinder VS dev environment but still having the full power of the Linux dev stack. Auto-generation of makefiles via VS project files too. Hope this helps.

Comment: For Visual Studio 2015 you can use the Visual C++ for Linux extension. https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/725025cf-7067-45c2-8d01-1e0fd359ae6e