# VisualStudio - how to run and compile C on linux server

Tags: c, visual-studio, compilation, server, external

We have had a group project in C (writing a compiler for brainfuck language). We had a pretty good project (with breakpoints, etc) but we ultimately failed the assignment because our code wouldnt run on the testsystem the university uses. Its a linux system.

Our tutor told us we should always use the server to compile and test our program to make sure its working correctly.

Now I asked her if its possible to compile and run the file on the server from Visual Studio, she said probably, and mentioned that in her (linux based) IDE its possible. (normally we copy over the file with filezilla, then from a sftp connection console access the server and compile and run our program on it wich is tedious, so much that one of us wrote a script that does this.... but at some point we ignored it and just debugged from visual studio)

Is it possible to use a directory of the server as working directory and when I hit "start debug" it opens a console but connected to the server where some parameters to compile and execute will be used?

I couldnt find anything on the web about this topic, maybe I dont know what im looking for / what this is called.

PS: I use VS2015, they probably do too.

@Basile Starynkevitch

ah yes, I love linux, in fact the last 2 people that came to me for laptop help I "talked into linux", and if I ever have to setup my pc new I'll also use it. but for now I dont want to change anything to my pc since its totally bloated with stuff and a windows partition and im scared to change anything.

@mikedu95
that was what i was looking for. in the linked thread the only solution was WinGDB wich costs up to 90 bucks per head. i think we will use a good ol script.

@Weather Vane 
The program does compile but doesnt run well / fails every testcase. (she even told us exactly what the differences are, why the problems have occured) we did do periodic tests, but the endphase was pretty heated (3 day coding weekend till 3 in the night) and for the last hours we didnt have time for testing on the server (if only we knew how different it runs on linux...)

@mah 
I did not ask to use a linux compiler in VS but to use the compiler that is on our server from VS. i know what a compiler and what an ide is

Comment: Visual Studio is an _IDE_, not a compiler. It comes with a compiler that targets Windows, not Linux. It is possible to acquire a Linux compiler that runs on Windows, and it is possible to configure your VS project to use that compiler. How to do these things is much too broad for Stack Overflow. You might google "linux compiler in visual studio", which appears to have many relevant links.

Comment: *"Our tutor told us we should always use the server to compile and test our program to make sure its working correctly."* You were not clear whether C code would not compile on the uni server, or would compile but not run, or locally compiled code would not run. If only you had made periodic tests on the server as work proceeded...

Comment: Do you mean doing thing like this ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15236389/visual-studio-remote-compile-and-run

Comment: You should consider installing Linux on your own laptop. It is a very good environment to learn programming. Linux being mostly free software, you'll learn a lot studying their source code and improving some of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visual Studio has a GDB extension for remote debugging on Linux. Instructions are in [the blog post here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2015/11/18/announcing-the-vs-gdb-debugger-extension.aspx)... basically, the copy-the-files-over-and-build part of the process is automated using putty. Somewhat cumbersome (for larger projects a file share is probably more appropriate) but it seems to work.

Comment: installing this extension throws this error message: This extension cannot be installed because the following references are missing:
- Microsoft.VisualStudio.Android.VC                          Microsoft Visual Studio Emulator for Android requires Windows 8. I guess I just use Putty and the command line (wich is sad because the debugging in VS is awesome) thanks tho!

Comment: Hmm, I'm guessing the "requires Windows 8" is for Hyper-V for emulated Android VMs, whereas you really just need the VS extension bits. If you can convince those to install somehow, it might still work.